# React Native, Redux not updating components on state change after combineReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Stack Overflow Gods,

I am new to Redux and am working on pulling data from a database and using it to create an initial state object for Redux using Redux Thunk.

My reducer file structure currently looks like:

- reducers

  - index.js
  - initialData.js

My components re-renders perfectly when I have the reducer that handles these interactions within index.js:

```js
import {GET_INITIAL_DATA_FULFILLED, GET_INITIAL_DATA_PENDING, GET_INITIAL_DATA_REJECTED} from '../constants/action-types'

const initialState = {
  chats : [],
  messages: [],
  user: {},
  loading:true,
  errorMessage:''
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_INITIAL_DATA_PENDING:
      // console.log('loading')
      return {
        ...state,
        loading:action.payload
      };
    case GET_INITIAL_DATA_FULFILLED:
      // console.log('Data recieved')
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload.user,
        messages:action.payload.messages,
        chats: action.payload.chats,
        loading:action.loading
      };
    case GET_INITIAL_DATA_REJECTED:
      // console.log('Error getting data')
      return {
        ...state,
        errorMessage: action.payload,
        loading: action.loading
      };
    default:

      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer
```

However, when I want to decouple this from the root reducer and switch to using combineReducer, the components no longer re-renders. This is that implementation:

**index.js**

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import initialData from './initialData'

export default combineReducers({
  initialData
})
```

**initialData.js**

```js
import {GET_INITIAL_DATA_FULFILLED, GET_INITIAL_DATA_PENDING, GET_INITIAL_DATA_REJECTED} from '../constants/action-types'

const initialState = {
  chats : [],
  messages: [],
  user: {},
  loading:true,
  errorMessage:''
}

const initialData = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_INITIAL_DATA_PENDING:
      console.log('loading')
      return {
        ...state,
        loading:action.payload
      };
    case GET_INITIAL_DATA_FULFILLED:
      console.log('Data recieved')
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload.user,
        messages:action.payload.messages,
        chats: action.payload.chats,
        loading:action.loading
      };
    case GET_INITIAL_DATA_REJECTED:
      console.log('Error getting data')
      return {
        ...state,
        errorMessage: action.payload,
        loading: action.loading
      };
    default:
      return {...state};
  }
}

export default initialData
```

If anybody has any ideas as to why my component is not re-rendering, despite the data being received and the state being updated I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. combineReducer creates a new property on the state object. So the component was just rendering an undefined state as I wasn't checking for that new property.